# Rectangles Intersection (Vertical line)

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, intersection, rectangles

For a given rectangle `R1` I am trying to find out which are the other rectangles that could intersect with it ***IF*** I draw a vectical line segment.

The rectangles that intersect with `R1` are marked in Red.

Every rectangle is characterized by its `(top, left)` and `(bottom, right)` coordinates.

```
R1 = [top, left, bottom, right],...,Rn = [top, left, bottom, right]
```

By using the coordinates and the vertical line. I want to find the rectangles that intersects with R1

## Solution

I found the following library which does the same work as the icl boost library but must simpler:
download site: [https://github.com/ekg/intervaltree][2]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "IntervalTree.h"

using namespace std;

struct Position
{
    int x;
    int y;
    string id;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Interval<Position>> intervals;
    intervals.push_back(Interval<Position>(4,10,{1,2,"r1"}));
    intervals.push_back(Interval<Position>(6,10,{-6,-3,"r2"}));
    intervals.push_back(Interval<Position>(8,10,{5,6,"r3"}));

    vector<Interval<Position> > results;
    vector<string> value;
    int start = 4;
    int stop = 10;

    IntervalTree<Position> tree(intervals);
   // tree.findContained(start, stop, results);
    tree.findOverlapping(start, stop, results);
    cout << "found " << results.size() << " overlapping intervals" << endl;
}
```

---

## Example

- LEFT = 4;
- RIGHT = 10;
- structure {1,2,"rc1"};

intervals.push_back(Interval(4,10,{1,2,"r1"}));

[image: Rectangles]

Comment: What do you have problem with? What have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to find out if this problem exists and if there is a specific algorithm to solve it @JoachimPileborg

Comment: I was going towards the idea of **sweep line algorithm**. But sounded too complex for me. I wanted to find an easier way to do it

Comment: do you mean "find all rectangles that intersect with any vertical line that can be drawn through R1" ? I'm asking because this is entirely 1D problem of overlapping line segments.

Comment: @Agent_L yes That's what I want. All rectangles that intersect with any vertical line that can be drawn through R1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't care where the rectangles are vertically.  You can project everything onto the x-axis and then solve the corresponding 1-dimensional problem: you have a set of intervals and you want to know which overlap with a given interval.  This is exactly what an interval tree is does:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: Cotton can you please explain a little bit on th projection. What are the intervals?

Comment: Projecting a point (x, y) onto the x-axis is x.  Projecting a rectangle (top, left), (bottom, right) onto the x-axis is the interval [left, right].

Comment: Excuse me @Cotton last comment Just to see if I got it right. Every rectangle will be projected onto the X-axis. So i will have the following list:

`[[left1,right1], [left2,right2],....,[leftn,rightn]]` I will construct an inverval Tree and see if they overlap?

Operations:
1) Add the intervals
2) Given an interval x, find if x overlaps with any of the existing intervals.

Comment: Yep!  I think that should do it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Your need a [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) algorithm. In C++ there's [boost.geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection.html) for doing such things among many others.

Answer (score 1):

Where:

- Rect is a collection of all rectangles.
- R is the rectangle to test
- x1 is one x-coordinate
- x2 is other x-coordinate

Pseudo Code

```
// make sure x1 is on the left of x2
if (R.x1 > R.x2)
    tmp = R.x2
    R.x2 = R.x1
    R.x1 = tmp
end if

for each Rect as r
    // don't test itself
    if (R != r)
        // make sure x1 is on the left of x2
        if (r.x1 > r.x2)
            tmp = r.x2
            r.x2 = r.x1
            r.x1 = tmp
        end if

        if ((r.x2 < R.x1) // if r rect to left of R rect
                || (r.x1 > R.x2)) // if r rect to right of R rect
            // r rect does not intersect R rect
        else
            // r rect does intersect R rect
        end if
    end if
end for
```