# interval_map boost library

Tags: c++, boost, set, intervals

In response to question: [Previous Answer: rectangle overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264651/rectangles-intersection-vertical-line)

I am using the `interval_map` as follows:
I have a set of rectangles defined by `R = [int start, int end, (int Top, int bottom,string id)]`
**N.B: Rectangles are projected onto the x-axis==>line segments**

- I want to store these Line segments in an inverval_map structure
- For a query line segment I want to find all the line segments that overlap with it

---

Source code:

```
#include "boost/icl/interval.hpp"
#include "boost/icl/interval_map.hpp"
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct Position{
    int top;
    int bottom;
    string id;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::set<Position> ids1;
    ids1.insert({10,10,"line1"});
    std::set<Position> ids2;
    ids2.insert({200,10,"line2"});
    boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::set<Position>> mymap;
    auto i1 = boost::icl::interval<int>::closed(2, 7);
    auto i2 = boost::icl::interval<int>::closed(3, 8);
    mymap += make_pair(i1, ids1);
    mymap += make_pair(i2, ids2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

## Another Library, and a solution but by not using the icl boost library

I found the following library which does the same work as the icl boost library but must simpler:
download site: [Interval Tree](https://github.com/ekg/intervaltree)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "IntervalTree.h"

using namespace std;

struct Position
{
    int x;
    int y;
    string id;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Interval<Position>> intervals;
    intervals.push_back(Interval<Position>(4,10,{1,2,"r1"}));
    intervals.push_back(Interval<Position>(6,10,{-6,-3,"r2"}));
    intervals.push_back(Interval<Position>(8,10,{5,6,"r3"}));

    vector<Interval<Position> > results;
    vector<string> value;
    int start = 4;
    int stop = 10;

    IntervalTree<Position> tree(intervals);
   // tree.findContained(start, stop, results);
    tree.findOverlapping(start, stop, results);
    cout << "found " << results.size() << " overlapping intervals" << endl;
}
```

---

## Example

- start = 4;
- Stop = 10;
- structure {1,2,"rc1"};

intervals.push_back(Interval(4,10,{1,2,"r1"}));

Comment: You are missing the closing `}` on the initializer list in the `make_pair` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to use the inverval library for something it's not quite designed for.

Have you looked at the `rtree` implementation from Boost Geometry?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html

The `query` method supports a number of spatial predicates:

- `contains()`
- `covered_by()`
- `covers()`
- `disjoint()`
- `intersects()`
- `overlaps()`
- `within()`

Most of which can also be used `negated`. Additional criteria are supported. As a special criterion [`boost::geometry::index::nearest()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/group__predicates/nearest_point_const____unsigned_.html#group__predicates_1ga987bd55f6b4698d19a935e079e48517f) can be used, which results in a k-nearest algorithm search.

Comment: I'll take a look. No I never used R-tree.

Actually @sehe The rectange is projected to the x-axis. So i'll be dealing with a list of intervals. My only problem is with `interval_map<int,description>` why is my declaration wrong.?

Comment: Okay. I didn't quite understand that you already projected onto a line (because you mentioned you have rectangles).

Comment: Sorry My mistake. sorry

Comment: @Hani Goc: Have in mind that in the R-tree you can index using n-dimensional boxes. This means that they may also be 1-d which would be an equivalent of intervals. Then you could use the R-tree to search Boxes/intervals e.g. intersecting or within other intervals or nearest to some 1d Point/value. However with the R-tree you could just find 2d Boxes intersecting some 2d Segment.